# JBOSS is not starting using standalone

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to run the JBOSS server in standalone mode. I have set up JBOSS_HOME, JAVA_HOME. When I try to run standalone in cmd(administrator), it just says calling standalone.conf.bat and then nothing happens.

I checked http:\localhost:8080, it is not opening which means server is not started.

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To start JBoss 7 on windows use `standalone.bat` script and to access management console, default URL is `localhost:9990`.

Comment: I was able to find out the problem. I did not have .war folder in the deployments folder which is why I was not able to open it..